# AngularJS - How do I push key value pairs into an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I'm attempting to push a new object with some key:value pairs into an array using AngularJS, and seem to be running into some trouble.

Here's the html:

```
<div class="small-12  medium-6 large-6 columns">

  <div id="addSubTarget">   
    <p>Add Targets</p>
    <input type="text" ng-model="sublevel.tagName">
    <button type="button" class="resultsButton" ng-click="addTag()">Submit</button>
  </div>

  <div id="addSubTargetBox">
    <p>Targets Added</p>
    <div id="targetAddedBox">
      <div class="targetAddedInBox" ng-repeat="tag in tagsFeed track by $index">
        {{tag}}
        <i class="fa fa-trash-o" title="Delete this tag" ng-click="deleteTag($index)"></i>
      </div>
    </div>                      
  </div>

</div>

<div class="small-12  medium-6 large-6 columns">    

  <div class="sublevelAddTextArea">
    <p>Instructions</p>
    <textarea rows="4" ng-model="sublevel.instructions"></textarea>
  </div>

  <div class="sublevelAddTextArea">
    <p>Response</p>
    <textarea rows="4" ng-model="sublevel.response"></textarea>
  </div>

</div>
```

And the button here:

```
<button type="button" class="resultsButton" ng-click="submitNewSub()">Submit</button>
```

Here's the function in the controller:

```
$scope.submitNewSub = function(){

  var arrayForUse = [];

  arrayForUse.push({
    tag: $scope.tagsFeed,
    instructions: $scope.sublevel.instructions,
    response:$scope.sublevel.response
  });

  console.log(arrayForUse);

  $scope.listTable.push(arrayForUse);

}
```

I am using a hard coded array for testing it looks like this:

```
$scope.listTable = [{
  tag: "tags 1",
  instructions: "instructions 1",
  response: "response 1"
},
{
  tag: "tags 2",
  instructions: "instructions 2",
  response: "response 2"
}];
```

I basically need those inputs to push onto that array in that structure so angular two-way data binding will update my front end, however something seems to not be working for me.

Comment: It looks like you're pushing an array into an array instead of an object into an array. I do not understand the point of arrayForUse, why not just $scope.listTable.push({tag:$scope.tagsFeed, instructions:$scope.sublevel.instructions, response:$scope.sublevel.response});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to push each element from the `arrayForUse` array one by one, not the whole array at once. Therefore you will want to change `$scope.listTable.push(arrayForUse)` by:

```
Array.prototype.push.apply($scope.listTable, arrayForUse);
```

Which takes each element in `arrayForUse` and pass it to the push method as a single call (equivalent to: `$scope.listTable.push(arrayForUse[0], arrayForUse[1], arrayForUse[2], ...);`

Answer (score 1):

The code you have above is pushing an array onto an array:

```
var arrayForUse = [];
arrayForUse.push({tag:$scope.tagsFeed, instructions:$scope.sublevel.instructions, response:$scope.sublevel.response});

$scope.listTable.push(arrayForUse);
```

Is this what you want?  Your hardcoded test array above seems to indicate you just need an array.